# Underground sea in Titan(Saturn's moon), water or hydrocarbons?

Tags: space, water, titan

Is the underground sea on Titan formed of water or hydrocarbons. Is anyone certain?

I have read a lot of various documents from NASA and Cassini missions and Huygens missions, and I have become confused.

Comment: What have you read?  Could you [edit] a link into the question?

Comment: Various documents from NASA and Cassini missions and Huygens missions.

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani please explain which one's you've read. It helps when answering. Next time your question might be closed if you refer to stuff you've read without providing links or citations to what they are. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titan is believed to have a layer of liquid water under its surface, due to tidal heating of the icy crust.

Titan has a surface formed of ices with some hydrocarbon (methane) lakes. The crust of Titan is mostly water ice.  Below this, there is a liquid water layer and perhaps more ice and silicate rocks below that.

This is described at https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2012/28jun_titanocean